# Using feminine plural inclusively

Tags: neutralidad-de-género

Traditionally, I'm aware, `vosotras` or `nosotras` implies a group of women only. While the masculine counterpart could imply a group of men or a mixed group.

I'm also aware that recently some people started to use `nosotras y nosotros` to make a statement about gender-inclusiveness.

But, do people, probably from the feminist collective or pushing for gender equality, also use `vosotras`, for example, to imply a group of mainly women, but not exclusively of women?

Comment: vosotras is only for women.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are people who use the feminine form of words to refer to groups containing both genders, such as [this group](https://blog.sinplastico.com/por-que-hablamos-en-femenino-generico/) or, apparently, [the trainer of the Spanish basketball team in 2018](https://www.fundeu.es/lenguaje-inclusivo/masculinogenerico.html). The political party "Podemos" also has run several times as "Unidas Podemos" for elections, and I assume they were also trying to include some men in that (although I could not find any explanation of their name on their website).

As the Fundéu link states, according to the Royal Academy, [only the generic masculine is correct](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/los-ciudadanos-y-las-ciudadanas-los-ninos-y-las-ninas). This may change if enough people start using other kinds of generic words. However, my impression for the moment is that all the alternative forms (generic feminine or made-up words like **nosotres* or **nosotrxs*) have too little usage in everyday language to consider a change of the rules.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when there are mostly women, they use vosotras but if it is 50/50 people are tending to say *nosotros y nosotras* because they don´t want to exclude feminine. But that depends if it is casual or formal. (In paper they put *nosotros/as* or *nosotrxs*).

Of course, *nosotros* is the correct way but people (including me) prefer to say *nosotros y nosotras*.

Answer (score 0):

En general y teóricamente es un error utilizar otro genérico que no sea el masculino, ya que el masculino se basa en su condición de término no marcado en la oposición masculino/femenino.

Por ello, es incorrecto emplear el femenino para aludir conjuntamente a ambos sexos, con independencia del número de individuos de cada sexo que formen parte del conjunto.

Sin embargo, en la vida real la teoría varia ligeramente y podemos encontrar diversas fórmulas que habitualmente atienden a un determinado sesgo político;

1 - Cuando se dirigen o implican a un grupo, en donde la gran mayoría son mujeres o el acto es para y para las mujeres normalmente se opta por dirigirse a la mayoría utilizando el genero mayoritario presente. Si la mayoría del público fuera de género masculino, se optaría por utilizar el género masculino. Cuando es difícil conocer cuál es la mayoría, los oradores o quienes escriben se refieren con el genérico masculino, nosotros, nosotros, todos nosotros...

2 - Si implican a un grupo heterogéneo de hombres y mujeres, en este caso, partidos políticos, asociaciones y otros grupos habitualmente de izquierda, se dirigen en las ponencias utilizando un lenguaje conjunto "Compañeros y Compañeras", "Nosotros y Nosotras", "Todos y Todas", "Vosotros y Vosotras"... , en una redundancia del lenguaje con la que convivimos desde hace lustros.

La RAE critica este uso del lenguaje y afirma de forma repetida que el masculino gramatical no constituye ningún tipo de discriminación y por tanto este tipo de lenguaje es incorrecto, aunque de hecho se sigue utilizando.

3 - Si el colectivo es variado, aunque exista mayoría de mujeres, y se pretende abrir el concepto de géneros entonces utilizan conjuntamente "Vosotros, Vosotras, Vosotres", "Nosotros, Nostras, Nosotres"...

Igualmente, este tipo de lenguaje, utilizado por partidos políticos y asociaciones con sesgo marcadamente de ultra-izquierda, es rechazado por la RAE y aunque se puede utilizar independientemente "Nosotros, Nosotras..." La utilización de "Nosotres", elle, le... para referirse a cualquier tipo de genero, tampoco esta admitido.

Comment: Esta lista pretenden ser reglas oficiales (link?) o es la forma de hablar de un determinado grupo de personas? Porque la RAE [solo acepta el masculino genérico](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/los-ciudadanos-y-las-ciudadanas-los-ninos-y-las-ninas) y la pregunta que ha hecho OP es si existe gente que lo haga de otra manera...

Comment: Lo siento, mi intención era la de hacer un repaso general a la sociedad sin entrar en los sesgos de corte político que lleva el utilizar determinado lenguaje. Gracias por el comentario.